# How do you get transistor voltage when you only have currents?

Tags: voltage, transistors, npn, homework

[image]

β=50 I need to find Vbe and Vce

So obviously it is a NPN transistor, the current is flowing in the same direction so it is in active mode.

Ie=Ic+Ib

1.2mA=1mA+Ib

Ib=0.2mA

Vbe should be around 0.7V for it wok but what about Vce?

Comment: Tony discusses this in his own way. But I think you are supposed to take note of two things. (1) \$V_\text{BE}\$ for small signal silicon devices will be roughly \$700\:\text{mV}\$ [room temp] when at \$1\:\text{mA}\$ collector current. (Not strictly true and saturation vs active matters, too. But you don't have much info.) (2) You know that in active mode that \$\beta=50\$. But in this case you have \$\beta=5\$. So the next thing you are supposed to realize is that this means it is saturated. If saturated \$V_\text{CE}\$ will be "small" (about \$200\:\text{mV}\$, more or less.)

Answer (score 1):

No.  All transistors have Vbe= 0.60 V at Ic=1mA in linear mode if collector current is regulated, but rise with Ib*Rbe .

Otherwise if Ie has 0.2mA base current added, (20%) it is in saturation where Vce(sat) is usually defined as Ic/Ib=10 but may generally thought as approx 10% of hFE max linear mode for decent saturation.

You show Ic/Ib=5.  Vce then becomes a function if transistor size and Vce(sat)/Ic= Rce=0.2/1m= 200 Ohms which is a very high.

If you had Vce=0.2 V as suggested in another answer, it would be a very tiny chip for this much saturation voltage at 1mA.

PN2222A’s are around 4 Ohms for Rce at rated current.

Some parts are designed with hFE= 500 to 2000 and thus require less base current to be saturated and are rated at Ic/Ib=50

Remember that the difference of Vce is the difference in diode voltages of a heavily dobed small junction for Vbe and the other being Vcb both being nearly the same when the current small enough at 1mA so the diode resistance drop is tiny.  Thus Rce a rarely specified value is valuable to know.

But chip temp affects Vbe as you know diodes make good thermometers with a neg. tempco (NTC), so my inital statement is ~true for all transistors at Tj=25'C

Answer (score 1):

> the current is flowing in the same direction so it is in active mode.

This is an incorrect inference.

There is another mode where the emitter and collector currents flow in the same direction.

Once you have worked out the correct operating mode, you'll be closer to figuring out the voltages.